# How to let the user know he has to refresh the page to get the latest application version / latest content?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

What should be the approach to notify a user that the content on the page has changed and he needs to refresh it ? The only think that is going in my mind is implementing a websocket that listens to the application version number. But I'm not sure if this is expensive in terms of server resources.

Comment: I believe there is no better solution other than WebSockets until this day ... another approach can be server polling which is more expensive

Comment: @Jora yes ... or simple ping request that can be made withing an interval ( ex: 5 mins )